# sales.rule.update.coupon.usage not working

Tags: magento2.4.3

We have magento 2 site and we had found this consumer queue is not working due to which we are facing issue

sales.rule.update.coupon.usage

please help

Answer (score 1):

There is an official fix for this issue. Please for more details [see url here](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/troubleshooting/miscellaneous/coupon-code-used-more-than-once-adobe-commerce.html?lang=en).

The fix for the issue is adding sales.rule.update.coupon.usage consumer to the app/etc/env.php file.

```
'cron_consumers_runner' =>
array [
    'cron_run' => true,
    'max_messages' => 20000,
    'consumers' =>
    array [
        'sales.rule.update.coupon.usage'
    ]
],
```